# prolog, user choice coffee menu

Tags: list, menu, prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog course, I am trying to write code to allow the user to choose the coffee then ask hot or cold then the size of the coffee to calculate price. I was looking on the web explain in how to develop the program but I feel it's different from what I need in the example: [animal identification][1]. Can you please help me to write the coffee menu.

Here is what I have tried.

```
  go :- hypothesize(Coffee),
  write('Your order is : '),
  write(Coffee),
  write('and the price for your order =  : ')
  nl,
  undo.

    /* hypotheses to be tested */
  hypothesize(moca)   :- moca, !.
  hypothesize(hotChocolate)     :- hotChocolate, !.
  hypothesize(latte)   :- latte, !.
   hypothesize(cappuccino)     :- cappuccino, !.

  /*   rules */
  moca :-
      /* ask if you want hot or cold
       * ask the size of the coffee*/
```

Is my method correct or better to create a list and then the user chooses by type the name of the coffee?

add the menu like this

```
    menu :- repeat,
    write('pleaase, Choose the Coffe to order:'),nl,
    write('1. Moca'),nl,
    write('2. Latte'),nl,
    write('3. Hot Choclate'),nl,

    write('Enter your choice number please: '),nl,
    read(Choice),
    run_opt(Choice).
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Is this for homework or on your own? If this is for your own use you can make life easier by forgoing the input prompts and concentrating on the logic first.

Comment: thank you for responding, this for homework. how should I concentrate in logic?

Comment: Being homework, it would be helpful if you gave put up the assignment so that we know the requirements. I am thinking that you have a list of choices and the prices for each choice, maybe even prices that are dependent on two or more options.

Comment: When I write Prolog code I tend to start with the low level logic first and the work up to a user interface if it is needed. In this case it is needed.

Comment: Basically the logic would take in a list of options, iterate through the list adjusting the price and return a final price. Then after that you could add the user interface to collect the list of options and then output the final price.

Comment: I would write some sample code, but without seeing the requirements it would be a back and forth discussion instead of a question then an answer.

Comment: it's only the topic (coffee order), no requirements but no need for interface. just I need how to write the logic to move ahead with the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something simple.

You first need a table of options and prices, but in Prolog these can be done simply as facts.

```
price(moca,2.0).
price(hotChocolate,1.5).
price(latte,2.5).
price(cappuccino,3.0).

price(cold,0.1).
price(hot,0.5).

price(short,1.0).
price(tall,1.5).
price(grande,2.0).
price(venti,2.5).
price(trenta,3.0).
```

Next you need to decide on the arguments for the predicate, in this case that is easy, a list of options for the input and a price for the output.

```
coffeeOrder(Options,Price)
```

Since there are a list of options the code needs to process a list and one of the easiest ways for a beginner is to use a recursive call. A recursive set of predicates follows the pattern of a base case

```
% Do something when the list is empty.
coffeeOptions([], ... ).
```

and a predicate to handle processing the list recursively

```
% Do something when the list is not empty.
coffeeOptions([H|T],PriceIn,PriceOut) :-
    % do something with the head, H
    coffeeOptions(T,NewPrice,PriceOut).
```

When generating a value, in this case the final price, and using a recursive call, often a helper predicate is needed to set up an initial value, in this case the initial cost which is 0.0.

So the predicates are:

```
coffeeOrder(Options,Price) :-
    coffeeOptions(Options,0.0,Price).  % This sets the initial price to 0.0.

% Do something when the list is empty.
coffeeOptions([],Price,Price).

% Do something when the list is not empty.
coffeeOptions([Option|T],Price0,Price) :-
    price(Option,Cost),
    Price1 is Price0 + Cost,
    coffeeOptions(T,Price1,Price).
```

And a quick test.

```
?- coffeeOrder([moca,hot,grande],Price).
Price = 4.5.
```

All of the code as one snippet.

```
coffeeOrder(Options,Price) :-
    coffeeOptions(Options,0.0,Price).

coffeeOptions([],Price,Price).

coffeeOptions([Option|T],Price0,Price) :-
    price(Option,Cost),
    Price1 is Price0 + Cost,
    coffeeOptions(T,Price1,Price).

price(moca,2.0).
price(hotChocolate,1.5).
price(latte,2.5).
price(cappuccino,3.0).

price(cold,0.1).
price(hot,0.5).

price(short,1.0).
price(tall,1.5).
price(grande,2.0).
price(venti,2.5).
price(trenta,3.0).
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative explanation, but how to set up a menu to choose by the user

Comment: @ADH Like said, this should not turn into a discussion. Please ask a new question.

Comment: ok :( , thank you for the response, and your answer very helpful.

Comment: @ADH You say thank you, but you don't give me an accept vote or an up-vote.

Comment: I did it but according to the reputation not displayed but recorded.